# install4j installation terminates unexpectedly! Last log entry: "Creating JVM"

Tags: install4j

We have a install4j-base installation. It works on most of the machines where we install our software.

But newly we've been facing a problem. On one of the target machines the installation terminates in an unexpected way! 
The last text that install4j logs to the file i4j_nlog is "Createing JVM".

Do you know what caused the error?
Thank you.

Here is the excerpt from the file i4j_nlog:

```
...
Unpacking JRE done
JRE dir: C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jED93.tmp_dir1430996472\jre
LoadDLL (0, C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jED93.tmp_dir1430996472\jre, 0)
Got JRE location C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jED93.tmp_dir1430996472\jre (java exe: 0)
MinVersion: 1.6, MaxVersion: 1.7
Trying to load JVM-DLL from c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\e4jed93.tmp_dir1430996472\jre\bin\java.exe
Setting PATH C:\MKS\IntegrityClient\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Programs\apache-maven-3.0.4\bin;c:\Programs\apache-ant-1.8.4\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\e4jed93.tmp_dir1430996472\jre\bin
Trying c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\e4jed93.tmp_dir1430996472\jre\bin\hotspot\jvm.dll (exists 0)
Trying c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\e4jed93.tmp_dir1430996472\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll (exists 1)
Loading of JVM-DLL successful
launching program
GetTempPath returned 37 (last error 6)
make dir returned -1
expanding2 ${TEMP} to C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp in -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -Dinstall4j.xpIndeterminate=true -Dinstall4j.keepLog=true -Dinstall4j.alternativeLogfile=C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\setup_Test.log -Duser.language=en -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true.
adding options

vmoptions2: exe C:\temp\CD_TMP\INSTALL\Test\Rxx.xx\setupjre.exe file: C:\temp\CD_TMP\INSTALL\Test\Rxx.xx\setupjre.vmoptions, file: 00000000
vmoptions: opts2: C:\temp\CD_TMP\INSTALL\Test\Rxx.xx\setupjre.exe.vmoptions, file: 00000000
vmoptions2: exe C:\temp\CD_TMP\install\Test\Rxx.xx\setupjre.exe file: C:\temp\CD_TMP\install\Test\Rxx.xx\setupjre.vmoptions, file: 00000000
vmoptions: opts2: C:\temp\CD_TMP\install\Test\Rxx.xx\setupjre.exe.vmoptions, file: 00000000
default vmoptions file: 00000000
classpath entry 
vmoption count 15
vmoption 0: -Dexe4j.semaphoreName=Local\c:_temp_cd_tmp_install_Test_Rxx.xx_setupjre.exe
vmoption 1: -Dexe4j.isInstall4j=true
vmoption 2: -Dexe4j.moduleName=C:\temp\CD_TMP\INSTALL\Test\Rxx.xx\setupjre.exe
vmoption 3: -Dsun.java.command=C:\temp\CD_TMP\INSTALL\Test\Rxx.xx\setupjre.exe
vmoption 4: -Dexe4j.tempDir=C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jED93.tmp_dir1430996472
vmoption 5: -Dexe4j.unextractedPosition=29066367
vmoption 6: -Djava.library.path=C:\MKS\IntegrityClient\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Programs\apache-maven-3.0.4\bin;c:\Programs\apache-ant-1.8.4\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\e4jed93.tmp_dir1430996472\jre\bin
vmoption 7: -Dexe4j.consoleCodepage=cp0
vmoption 8: -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true
vmoption 9: -Dinstall4j.xpIndeterminate=true
vmoption 10: -Dinstall4j.keepLog=true
vmoption 11: -Dinstall4j.alternativeLogfile=C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\setup_Test.log
vmoption 12: -Duser.language=en
vmoption 13: -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true
vmoption 14: -Djava.class.path=C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jED93.tmp_dir1430996472\i4jruntime.jar;C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jED93.tmp_dir1430996472\user.jar;C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jED93.tmp_dir1430996472\platform.zip;
Creating JVM
```

Comment: Is there an hserr_pid... file in the working directory?

Comment: I've encountered exactly the same problem: On Windows 8, a customer can't install our install4j-built product, and the log file ends with "Creating JVM". Where would the working directory be?

Comment: I am facing the same error in year 2019 when installing our product on windows 10